# Child window in MVVM light

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

How can I use Messaging from MVVM Light in am WPF app for showing a ChildWindow and returning some values from it ?
what I need is to present to user a modal dialog with 2 datepickers and the message to return somehow theese 2 values for using as parameters to other views.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I just use a `Popup` for something like this.

The `Popup` usually has its `Visibility` bound to something like an `IsPopupVisible` property in the `ViewModel`, and the Popup `DataContext` is usually also part of the ViewModel

I'm not a huge fan of WPF's default `Popup` control, so I have my own custom Popup control [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) if you're interested.

It's typically used like this:

```
<local:PopupPanel Content="{Binding PopupContent}"
    local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=ParentPanel}"
    local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}" />
```

and I show it from the `ViewModel` like this:

```
PopupContent = new SelectDatesViewModel();
IsPopupVisible = true;
```

Once the `SelectDatesViewModel.SaveCommand` gets triggered, you can fire off a message containing the selected dates to whatever ViewModels are interested:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new DatesChangedMessage(this.Date1, this.Date2))
```

The actual popup content can either be defined in the XAML, or with an implicit `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SelectDatesViewModel}">
    <local:SelectDatesView />
</DataTemplate>
```